# WSDL Generation Failing in Jenkins but working in Local

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jenkins, wsdl

Here is my POM File

```
<build>

    <sourceDirectory>target/jaxws/wsimport</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>target/generated/${ebc.name.uppercase}/wsdl</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy templates</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.corp.ebcbuild</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ebcbuild-templates-client-wsdl</artifactId>
                                <version>${ebcbuild.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.ikea.${ebc.name.lowercase}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>DBI_${ebc.name.lowercase}_Contracts</artifactId>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ikea.ebcbuild</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ebcbuild-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${ebcbuild.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>codetranslator-generate-client-interface</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-client-interface</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetDirectory>target/generated/${ebc.name.uppercase}</targetDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <target>2.1</target>
                <sourceDestDir>target/jaxws/wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>com.ikea.${ebc.name.lowercase}.client.ws</packageName>
                    <wsdlDirectory>target/generated/${ebc.name.uppercase}/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

And here is the error trace from Jenkins

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on project ebcposrix01-interface: Mojo failed - check output -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on project ebcposrix01-interface: Mojo failed - check output
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Mojo failed - check output
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:393)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.processLocalWsdlFiles(WsImportMojo.java:319)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.execute(WsImportMojo.java:283)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo.execute(MainWsImportMojo.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

Am not a maven Expert, but  what confuses me is why is the same project failing Jenkins where it works fine in Local Environment.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the jaxws-maven-plugin configuration in pom.xml file it follows the documentation:
https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#wsdlDirectory

Apparently there  is a bug  in the below dependency

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
```

That the          mentioned in the pom.xml does not take spaces in the project path. And build server jobs had spaces in them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to project path, I had windows path separator added to the project path and jenkins is building on linux...